# Windows/Unix line ending issues in github

Tags: git, github

I have now migrated all my code to github and started seeing some differences in terms of file sizes. I realized it is because of line endings and I should use .gitattributes file for each repo .

I am using git in winodws and using  core.autocrlf true. But, I think its better to set .gitattributes per repo so its consistent for every developer. is it ok to do this now that I have already pushed the code to remote repo?

Comment: Have other people begun pulling/committing to the code base? If so, it may be a little problematic if you plan to switch things over now.

Comment: no I have just pushed the main code base with few commits. nobody else has commited.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that it's a best practice to use a `.gitattributes` file if you need to configure text handling and line-ending support. To avoid piecemeal conversion, you should run `git add --renormalize .` after modifying the `.gitattributes` file so that all of the files will be converted at once.

If you don't do this, files won't be converted until later, and you can end up with a mix of line endings in your repository, which can result in very noisy diffs and merge conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it is no problem if you change this.

If you want the repository to be consistant, you can (rebase it interactively and) amend commit the changes.